# How to create fake hover in angular?

Tags: angular, html, css

I have 10 divs that are populated with an image and text rendered as cards into a horizontal scroll which shows these cards 3 at a time, now i wish to create a fake hover effect on the middle card and keep the middle card hovered even when the cards are scrolled.
I am using Angular 6, thank you and please help me.

I can't think of anything but i did try to fix anchors at the divs and scroll them, it did not really work.

The expected result should be a horizontal cards which are scrolled but the middle card being highlighted with the help of the hover effect.

Comment: If you share the code you have now, and what you've tried, it will make it much easier for someone to help you, and provide a much better resource to someone else finding your question in the future with a similar requirement.

Comment: u need to apply dynamic class name to those div's and populate hover effect using CSS

Comment: What do you mean by a "fake" hover? Either the mouse is over an element or its not. Do you just want something to look different/active at some times?

Comment: Thank you and its supposed to have an hover effect even though the mouse is not there, what i want to achieve is the middle card always being highlighted while the elements are scrollable itself giving the effect that highlighted card is being read.

also sir the code is not effective that is the reason i have not shared but i would keep it in account the next time i ask a question, thank you for the kind notion.